# Do I have to create different database connection to clusters in node js app?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, database-connection, cluster-computing

I am developing node application using express.I heard about clustering is good way to increase app performance. So i tried this way,

```
if(cluster.isMaster){
  debug(`Master ${process.pid} is running`);

// Fork works
  for (let i =0;i<numCPU;i++){
      cluster.fork();
  }

  cluster.on('exit',(worker,code,signal)=>{
      debug(`Worker ${worker.process.pid} died.`);
  });
}else{

  var app = require('../app');
  app.set('port', port);

  var server = http.createServer(app);

  database.connect(function (err) {
      if (err){
          debug('Unable to connect MongoDB');
          process.exit(1);
      }else{
          server.listen(port);
      }
  });

  server.on('error', onError);

  debug(`Worker ${process.pid} start`);
}
```

My question is, before use cluster I created Mongo connection at the very beginning and use database instant. But now i repeat it for each time which create clusters. I feel I do some useless thing but i don't know how fix it. If this way of create database is wrong how can i fix it ? or Should I create database connection for each cluster, then is this method correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I got an answer from my lecturer. Now i know cluster not means it runs several applications, but gives several connections. So we don't have to create connection for each cluster or think about each cluster separately. What we have to do is create application and give cluster manager do do rest of things...